# What does "nukulate" mean?

Tags: meaning, errors

What does *nukulate* mean in the following sentence from a [question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/28406/what-type-of-milk-is-used-together-with-whole-grain-cereal) on Cooking SE?

> **Nukulate** for 3 minutes on high.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To [*nuke*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/nuke) is to *microwave*. *Nukulate* is probably a more informal variant.

Comment: No wonder I can't find it in the dictionary.

Comment: You think that *nuculate* is more informal than *nuke*?  *Nuke* is already extremely informal. This is on a different axis, perhaps.  Maybe *nuculate* is just a playful, tongue-in-cheekier kind of pseudo-formal formulation.

Comment: @tchrist: To *nuke* (from *nuclear bomb*) has been around since the late 50s, so it's reasonably well established, if a little informal. Most likely this neologism is (facetiously or ignorantly) "backformed" from *nuke*. Thus it lacks both the status of age and of respectable parentage - sounds like "a more informal variant" to me.

Comment: Interestingly enough, the word _nucleate_ is also associated with microwave ovens. (If you are heating water in a container (such as a new, smooth cup) that does not provide a sufficient environment to allow nucleation to occur, the water may become superheated and erupt and boil over when you pick the cup up.

Comment: This sounds like another instance of "chefs" wanting to invent new words to describe their efforts. _Jamie Oliver_ insists that you watch a pan closely when the contents are crispening (sic).

Comment: I'm guessing it's an informal variant formed by a portmanteau of *nuke + percolate*.